# After initializing byte array in constructor, it is returning null in the object

Tags: c#, byte

My code:

```
public class UplaodedFile
{
    public UploadedFile File = null;
    public string Description = null;
    public string OriginalFileName = null;
    public byte[] inputStream ; 

    public UplaodedFile(UploadedFile file, string desc, string FileName, byte[] inputStream)
    {
        File = file;
        Description = desc;
        OriginalFileName = FileName;
        inputStream = inputStream;
    }
}
```

I am creating an object as below:

```
UplaodedFile uploadedfile = new UplaodedFile(uploaded_file, description, originalFileName, file_contents);
```

and when I try to access the `uploadedfile.inputStream`, I am getting null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Rename your field to `InputStream` which should be done anyway because it's `public`. But you should not have public fields, instead use properties. Read [why properties matter](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to constructor's argument in constructor

Instead of

```
inputStream = inputStream;
```

You need to write

```
this.inputStream = inputStream;
```

Answer (score 0):

By setting

```
inputStream = inputStream;
```

you only assign to the parameter `inputStream`. As your class field is also named `inputStream` you need to tell the compiler to set it by using `this`:

```
this.inputStream = inputStream;
```